# Error: No Matching function to call to 'online'

Tags: c++

I know this is probably a really simple fix, but I'm having trouble finding what my error is, and none of the posts I've checked online have been able to help me. I get the error on the cout lines. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

bool online(int a, int network[a][a]) {
    /*post condition: returns true if every switch in a network is of even degree. Otherwise, returns false.*/
    int switches;
    for(int x=0; x < a; x++) {
        switches = 0;
        for(int y=0; y < a; y++)
            if(network[x][y])
                switches += 1;
        if(switches & 1)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int arrayOne[6][6] =
    {
        {0,1,1,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,1,1},
        {0,0,0,1,0,1},
        {0,0,0,1,1,0}
    };
    int arrayTwo[8][8] =
    {
        {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0}
    };
    std::cout << online(6, arrayOne) << std::endl;
    std::cout << online(8, arrayTwo) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Array has incomplete element type int '[]'` , and yes, the intention was to return false if there was an odd number in any row

Comment: Please only tag your post with the language you're using. I edited it down to just `c++`, if you're using a different language and I misread your post, please remove the `c++` tag and put only the specific language you're using.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error in the same spot.

Comment: I doubt there is any to correlate the array size to a parameter.  You'll have to use a more abstract array declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C99 (which supports variable length arrays), there is no `<iostream>`. Make sure you are compiling the program as C and not C++, and then use `<stdio.h>` instead, and include `<stdbool.h>`.

```
printf("%d\n", online(6, arrayOne));
printf("%d\n", online(8, arrayTwo));
```

For C++, variable length arrays may not be supported for your compiler. You should use a template instead for `online()`.

```
template <unsigned a>
bool online(int, int (&network)[a][a]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Just a question concerning your first sentence. Does C99 support arrays which have variable length in two dimensions?

Comment: Way to go jxh. You solved it! Is there a way to make the function without passing an int with the size?

Comment: @Dbz: Yes. The first parameter is unused, so you can define the function without the first parameter with no problem.